# Need help to set up script for Drupal8 in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, drupal-8, gitlab-ci

I am using https://github.com/Lullabot/drupal8ci for setup mine CI.

.gitlab-ci.yml is as https://gitlab.com/visabhishek/drupal8ci/blob/d20e514d219e092e5742217668ff4edf1326d632/.gitlab-ci.yml

Need help with setup DB configuration

I have tried to set $DB_DUMP_URL with DB path. but its giving error "Databases not found"

[image]
Is I am missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget to change my DB name under variables

```
    DB_URL: "mysql://root@mariadb/drupal8"
    SIMPLETEST_DB: "mysql://root@mariadb/drupal8"
```